# Referencing a function that returns a structure/derived type

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm struggling with a concise title, but it's not that complicated.  I have a function that returns a structure (derived type) and I'm looking for a simple way to reference only a part of the structure while calling the function (without copying/pointing to another structure).

```
program main

   real :: xx = 1.
   real :: yy = 2.

   ! works fine but what I want is to be 
   ! able to return %tx and %ts separately

   print *, " tax ", tax(xx,yy)

   ! just guessing at possible syntax here, but neither works

   print *, " tax ", tax%tx(xx,yy)
   print *, " tax ", tax(xx,yy)%tx

contains

function tax(x,y)

   real :: x, y

   type tTax
      real :: tx, ty
   end type tTax

   type(tTax) :: tax

   tax%tx = x * 100.
   tax%ty = y * 100.

end function tax

end program main
```

I'm restricted to f90/f95 feature set but feel free to include f2003 answers also.

And I'm really looking for something simple here, if it exists.  Otherwise, it's just going to be better to do as a subroutine (if the alternative is keeping it as a function but adding pointers, interfaces, etc.).

I also tried having the function return a 2 dimensional array instead of a structure and had the same basic problem -- it works, but I am only able to print the whole array, not any array sections by themselves.

I had trouble even guessing at the syntax there since `()` is used for both functions and array sections in fortran (as opposed to languages like python which uses `[]` for indexing, so it's fairly natural to mix functions and indexes e.g. something like `tax(xx,yy)[1,:]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a user-defined constructor by overloading the derived-data type's name with a function return.

Liberal use of the Fortran 2003 standard's `associate` construct allows one to access specific type-components without copying or resorting to memory-leak-prone pointers.

Is there any particular reason why you're restricting yourself to Fortran 2003; a great deal of Fortran 2008 is supported by most popular compilers.

The following code

```
module mymod

  ! Explicit typing only
  implicit none

  ! Declare derived data type
  type tTax
     real :: tx, ty
  end type tTax

  ! User-defined constructor
  interface tTax
     module procedure tax
  end interface tTax

contains

  function tax(x, y) result (return_value)
    real, intent (in) :: x, y
    type (tTax)       :: return_value

    return_value%tx = x * 100.0
    return_value%ty = y * 100.0

  end function tax

end module mymod

program main

  use mymod

  ! Explicit typing only
  implicit none

  real       :: xx = 1.0, yy = 2.0
  type(tTax) :: foo

  print *, " tax ", tax(xx,yy)
  print *, " tax ", tTax(xx, yy)

  ! Invoke the user-defined constructor
  foo = tTax(xx, yy)

  ! Fortran 2003's associate construct
  associate( &
       tx => foo%tx, &
       ty => foo%ty &
       )
       print *, " tax ", tx, ty
  end associate

end program main
```

yields

```
gfortran -Wall -o main.exe mymod.f90 main.f90
./main.exe
  tax    100.000000       200.000000    
  tax    100.000000       200.000000    
  tax    100.000000       200.000000
```

Comment: Thanks, +1.  As I guessed in the question, fortran makes this extra work so that from a practical point of view I may just go with a subroutine as it's a little simpler -- and at the moment I don't have a new enough compiler to test it anyway.  ;-)  But this is cool, thanks!

Comment: I know without f2003 I can't use `associate()` in main, but should the module by itself compile for me?  My f90 compiler complains about type and interface both using the tTax name, but will compile either of them separately (of course main doesn't work in those cases).  If I could just use foo%tx in main rather than tx that would be a sufficient solution from my perspecive.

Comment: @VladimirF or jlok:  is there any easy answer to my comment right above here?  Or is it worth asking as a separate question?

Comment: @JohnE Probably a separate question. It is not clear enough from your description. Maybe old compiler, maybe wrong code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the parenthesis symbols, it is just whether you are allowed to reference a component or element of an expression or not.

And in Fortran you are not allowed that. You can only use the % syntax or array indexing () on variable or constant names or on associate-names.

Comment: Right, that was my working assumption but I am always hoping for some python-esque syntactic sugar altho that seems to be against the fortran ethos.  ;-)

Comment: @JohnE Here's a link to the Python Fortran Rosetta Stone http://www.fortran90.org/src/rosetta.html

Comment: @jlokimlin yeah, that is nice altho interestingly for my problem it treats fortran **subroutines** as equivalent to python/numpy!  My problem here obviously that I'm trying to make a fortran function work like a python function and I may just be trying to hard to make fortran look more like python.